# MariaDB 10.0 JSON type with symfony 4

Tags: json, database, symfony, doctrine, mariadb

In my Linux server, I have MariaDB version 10.0 which does not support json type (supported until version 10.2) and I can't update it because it is not released in official ubuntu repository.

When I run the command `doctrine:migration:migrate` for creating tables I get a syntax error from MariaDB for json type

> MariaDB: 10.0.34 - PHP: 7.1 - Symfony: 4.0.6

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: This project worked in my local with MariaDB version 10.2.8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that Doctrine is expecting MariaDB 10.2+, but there have been problems getting the latest MariaDB versions into repos (Arch is still at 10.1).

The solution is here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration

Just configure `server_version` in `config/packages/doctrine.yml` to:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: 'mariadb-10.1.34'
    ...
```

Just replace the version with your version number which you can get with

```
$ mysql --version
```

Comment: Just a note modifying Doctrine with this change might cause problems with the advanced stuff as it could be expecting things to be present in the engine that are not.

Comment: @MartinBarker as I understand it this change is preventing exactly that. By telling doctrine the correct database version number (the bug is due to doctrine presuming you have a newer one) you avoid problems where Doctrine expects things to be present.

Comment: +1 because this answer digs into the real problem. Upgrading the database version is all right, but sooner or later you'll get into trouble again unless you change Doctrine configuration accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note, don't forget to delete the previous migrations that you generated with the old "server_version".

Everything is contained in the "/ migrations" directory of your project.

Answer (score -1):

```
* @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="string")
private $usuarioRoles;

public function getRoles(): array {
        $roles = explode(",",$this->usuarioRoles);
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
        return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self {
        $this->usuarioRol = implode(",",$roles);
        return $this;
}
```