# How to connect Symfony4 to mysql using docker

Tags: symfony, docker, symfony4

I am trying to connect (local development) symfony4 to a db in docker, this is the docker container

```
83d1b68ce44a        cytopia/mariadb-10.1:latest      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 days ago          Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp                       devilbox_mysql_1
```

web is working and fully configured, I don't understand what host should I use in the .env file.

thanks

Comment: Do you use Windows, Linux, macOS? The OSes use different ways to declare a Docker network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You binded the port 3306 to the host, so we have to tell Symfony to use this port. We have to use the address `127.0.0.1` because [with `localhost`, MySQL try to connect through a socket](https://superuser.com/a/250371/267546).

So you should end up with something like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://USER:PASSWORD@127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASE_NAME
```

You may need to configure the access to MariaDB:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: 'mariadb-10.2'
```

See [MariaDB 10.0 JSON type with symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51325380/2257664)

Answer (score 0):

Depending the usage you should try different approaches. Id you are NOT using a `docker_compose.yml` then try with hostname `0.0.0.0:3306` but in case of a dockerfile for example [this](https://github.com/ellakcy/moodle-compose/blob/master/docker-compose_maria_apache.yml) (It is for moodle but gets the job done).

So in the latter case I use the **service** name as host name in order to get the job done. Usually I use the `docker-compose.yml` approach in order to configure my running environment.

Also keep in mind using `docker-compose.yml` also users a `.env` file for configuration thus it may cause a conflict as well.

Answer (score 0):

`DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:password@mariadb:3306/databaseName`

This example "mariadb" is container alias name.